# Variable not expanded inside an included selmer template

Tags: clojure, luminus, selmer

I have a top-level template where I want to use a "fragment" template inside a for cycle but I'm not able to pass in the variable value:

```
  {% for item in coll %}
    {% include "fragment.html" with name="slack" item=item %}
  {% endfor %}
```

`item` and `name` is then used in the fragment.html template:

```
<div>
  <label>
    <input
      title="{{item.id}}"
      id="{{name}_{{item.id}}_active"
      name="{{name}}-{{item.id}}_active"
...
    />
```

While the `name` parameter is expanded properly (its value is hardcoded in the parent template), the `item` parameter is not (its value is passed in as is).

Do I need to use a different syntax for that or it's just not supported?

Comment: This question does not have anything to do with Clojure.

Comment: Selmer is a clojure library so I guess it does.

Answer (score 2):

The `include` tag splices in the included template. This means that any variables within scope of the parent template will be available to the included template. The `with` operator allows you to supply default values, which are not interpreted. Saying `item=item` is effectively saying `item|default:"item"`, which is to say that `item` is redefined as `"item"`.

See https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer#including-templates

Comment: Great, thanks for clarification. I've found this myself experimentally. Indeed, the `width` tag is what I reached for.

Comment: I messed around a little more, and I'm not entirely sure why the literal string "item" was being passed through for you. For me it's passing through the value of the `item` variable. Regardless, you don't need to say `item=item` anyway!

Comment: Oh yeah, and it's really just confusing to pass it explicitly since it always takes the value of the `item` variable from the outer scope anyway. So it's best to left it out and just use `with` in the surrounding context.